# How to determine which thread closures are run on in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, closures

I am trying to determine exactly which thread the three closures in the
code below are executed on. The `startLoggingAsync` is called in the main thread and is passed a `reader` argument (CLOSURE 1) which will be invoked at some time in the future after `startLoggingAsync` is finished.

CLOSURE 2 is called asynchronously on a background thread via a GCD `DispatchQueue`.

CLOSURE 3 is assigned to the `readabilityHandler` of a `Pipe` which is invoked whenever there is data on the `Pipe`'s `stdout`.

```
//
// ‘reader’ is CLOSURE 1 passed by caller
//
func startLoggingAsync(withReader reader : @escaping (_ data : String) -> Void)  {
    . . .
    let processQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    processQueue.async { // CLOSURE 2 ran on background thread
        self.process = Process()
        . . .
        let pipe = Pipe()
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        let outHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        outHandle.readabilityHandler = { pipe in // CLOSURE 3
            if let string = String(data: pipe.availableData, encoding: .utf8) {
               reader(string) // call CLOSURE 1 
           }
        }
        . . .
        process.waitUntilExit()
        outHandle.readabilityHandler = nil
    }
}
```

Clearly CLOSURE 2 runs on background thread. Which threads do CLOSURE 1 and 3 get executed on?

Comment: add breakpoint into closures and check the threads in Xcode?

Comment: @DominikBucher Yes -- Debug manager makes it quite clear -- I feel silly for posting the question now...